# how to resize the width of a pane in Visual Studio Code on linux using shortcut keys?

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code

I am looking for a quick shortcut to resize the with the current focused pane in VS Code. How can that be done?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't test on linux but there are two commands that may work for you:

`Increase Editor Width`
`Decrease Editor Width`

that are unbound by default.  For example, in your keybindings.json:

```
    {
        "key": "alt+-",
        "command": "workbench.action.decreaseViewWidth"
    },
    {
        "key": "alt+=",
        "command": "workbench.action.increaseViewWidth"
    }
```

[if by "current focussed pane" you mean an editor, and not the sideBar, Panel, etc.]

Comment: Where is the keybindings.json file located?

Comment: If 3 panes are open, it does not appear to have any effect on the middle pane

Comment: I assume you found the keybindings.json file - you can also set keybindings through the Gear Icon/Keyboard Shortcuts and then click on the pencil icon to input your keybinding.  If by middle pane do you mean you have 3 editor groups open?  Even in that case, or just three editors open (but no splits - all in one editor group), those commands I mentioned do resize the focused editor for me.

Comment: I have added a picture of what I meant by "pane". Yeah, I think it is the editor. There are 3 of them. And the command only works to resize the left and right panes, not the middle.